# preg_replace can't handle new line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an HTML document where I would like to remove block from (starting with date 20170908 ending with next script tag), however preg_replace can't detect anything that lies below the newline. If I manually erase newlines, reg expression works, but I'd like to trim them programmatically. A part of the HTML document:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="iam.js"></script><script 
        type="text/javascript"src="/search.js"></script><script 
        type="text/javascript" > /* 20170908 */ function uabpd4(){
        //some function
    } 
    </script>
```

In PHP I do the following:

```
    $content = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $content)); // just trying to get rid of newlines, but nothing from this works
    $content = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/is", "", $content);
    $content = str_replace(array("\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $content);
    $content = preg_replace("/\/\* $date(.*?)(((?!script>).)uabpd4(.*?script>))/is", "WORKS </script>", $content);
```

Thank you.

Comment: works fine https://regex101.com/r/E1yHVY/2

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, because you have removed the newline yourself..

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2b94f8a99ebb73069df0b626eee3ca8ea877c3b3 works for me

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://regex101.com/r/Hze8wo/1

Comment: Again: I would like to remove block from (starting with date 20170908 ending with next script tag)

Comment: And Again: What do you mean by that? Can you give us an expected output?

Comment: basically the script tag will not contain this anymore  "/* 20170908 */ function uabpd4(){
        //some function
    }"

Comment: There is no "basically". Just edit your question, copy paste the code and edit to make a expected output.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="iam.js"></script><script type="text/javascript"src="/search.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" ></script>

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want to remove the javascript part with the date in it.

This is one method, match the part you want to remove and use str_replace to remove it.

```
$re = '/.*script type.*<script.*type.*?>(.*?uabpd4.*})/s';
$str = '<script type="text/javascript" src="iam.js"></script><script 
        type="text/javascript"src="/search.js"></script><script 
        type="text/javascript" > /* 20170908 */ function uabpd4(){
        //some function
    } 
    </script>';

preg_match($re, $str, $m);

echo str_replace($m[1], "",  $str);
```

https://3v4l.org/ktcXo

Comment: My problem is not my regular expression, it does work, but the fact that it doesn't work when there are new lines. Problem is still there.

Comment: This works with new lines too. I don't understand the problem... https://3v4l.org/VhEKe